# How can i change the application name in xamarin android?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

### Explaination

The icon label is being overwritten by the Label specified on my Main Activity Label.

My AndroidManifest.xml has:

```
<manifest>
<application android:label="@string/app_name" />
</manifest>
```

My AssemblyInfo.cs has:

```
#if DEBUG
[assembly:Application(Debuggable=true, Label="@string/app_name")]
#else
[assembly:Application(Debuggable=false, Label="@string/app_name")]
#endif
```

My String.xml has:

```
<string name="app_name">MyApp</string>
```

My MainActivity.cs has:

```
[Activity (Label = "Demo App")]
```

When I email the apk to the phone, gmail asks me to install 'MyApp', which appears to be coming from the manifest or the Assembly. However, the icon on the App Launch screen shows 'Demo App', which is coming from the MainActivity.cs.

### Question

I want the Label from the Activity to be appearing as the title of the app(Demo App), whereas I want the App launch name to be 'MyApp'. Can I override the title somehow to get this working?

### Answer

My AndroidManifest.xml has:

```
<manifest>
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/AppIcon"/>
</manifest>
```

In String.xml has:

```
<string name="app_name">MyApp</string>
<string name="Home">Demo App</string>
```

In  MainActivity.cs:
Instead of this

```
[Activity (Label = "Demo App")]
```

use `ActionBar` to set title,icon. Then you will get different name in app launch screen and home screen.

```
[Activity(MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTop,)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.main);
        ActionBar.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
        ActionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.Home);
    }
}
```

Comment: So... you want to swap the two values?

Comment: @SamAxe No i don't want to swap any values.. I want show app launch screen name as 'MyApp' but it is showing 'Demo App' in app launch screen which is present in present in activity page. It is overriding the application name with activity name.

Comment: you need to change in My String.xml file make it as <string name="app_name">Any name here...</string>

Comment: @GurudathG I have given the name in that file itself as <string name="app_name">MyApp</string> its not appearing in app launch screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the Label from the Activity to be appearing as the title of the app(Demo App), whereas I want the App launch name to be 'MyApp'.

Remove the `Label` of the `MainActivity`, set the application in the `Manifest.xml` via UI or code:

```
<manifest ...>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" />
</manifest>
```

If your `MainActivity` is `AppCompatActivity`, you could use `Toolbar` to display the `Activity` label:

```
[Activity(MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTop, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.main);
        var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null)
        {
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            SupportActionBar.Title = "Demo App";
        }
    }
}
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP0um.gif)

## Update:

Here is my `toolbar.axml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

`main.axml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Shen -MSFT  I am using MainActivity as Activity so how may i use it?

Comment: @Anish, can you change your `MainActivity` type to `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: @Anish, it is recommended to use `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`.

Comment: @Anish, I have post my complete code, hope this can help you. if there is still any problem, please feel free to ask. :)

Comment: @ York Shen - MSFT Thank you for your time. I will try your answer also but for now i got it, i have updated my question to see the answer.

Comment: @ York Shen - MSFT Yeah sure :)