# Dynamically change the label name of an application that is set by attributes on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am developing with Xamarin.Forms.
NET Standard class in C# to dynamically change the name of the application label that is set in the attributes of Droid/MainActivity.cs.
Forexample "SG2022" to "NEW_SG20220214".

```
namespace SG2022.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "SG2022", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
```

NET Standard class in C#. For example, if I can change it from the LoginViewModel, how do I write it?

```
public LoginViewModel()
{
    LoginCommand = new Command(OnLoginClicked);
    Droid.Activity.Label = "NEW_SG20220214";
}
```

Is it possible to write something like

Comment: check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44613974/how-to-change-android-application-name-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, the information in the thread in this link is not enough. The attributes in the information in the thread and also in the Manifest require the application name to be determined statically at compile time. I am looking for a way to dynamically change it from within the application.

Comment: Hope this link (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce488ad6-476f-442e-94ad-9c163f2f07a8/dynamic-app-name-and-app-icon-in-xamarinforms?forum= xamarinforms) can help you.

Comment: Thanks Wen for your comment. However, the information in the thread in this link is not enough.

Comment: This link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48337869/how-can-i-change-the-application-name-in-xamarin-android) is a modification through code.